# Product of Householder Matrix and Givens Rotation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Can someone explain why the following is true? 
"The product of a Householder transformation matrix and a Givens rotation matrix is always an orthogonal matrix."

Comment: The product of orthogonal matrices is orthogonal. $(HG)^* HG = G^* H^* H G = I$.